# Why did the obj variable assigned twice? (array of object, javascript)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I want to print one object after mentioning the name. But why it becomes twice and both objects are printed?

This is the output:

```
1. Christ Evans
{ firstName: 'Christ', lastName: 'Evans', gender: 'Male', age: 38 }
{
  firstName: 'Robert',
  lastName: 'Downey',
  gender: 'Male',
  age: 'Invalid Birth Year'
}
2. Robert Downey
{ firstName: 'Christ', lastName: 'Evans', gender: 'Male', age: 38 }
{
  firstName: 'Robert',
  lastName: 'Downey',
  gender: 'Male',
  age: 'Invalid Birth Year'
}
```

I only want to print once and the correct object, after mentioning the name.

Here's my code:

```
function changeMe(arr) {
    let person = [];
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        person.push(`${arr[i][0]} ${arr[i][1]}`)
    }

    for(i=0;i<person.length;i++){
        var urut = i+1;
        console.log(`${urut}. ${person[i]}`);
        for(j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
            var obj = {}  
            if(arr[j].length==4 && 2020-arr[j][3]>0){
                obj.firstName = arr[j][0]
                obj.lastName = arr[j][1]
                obj.gender = arr[j][2]
                obj.age = 2020 - arr[j][3]
            }else{
                obj.firstName = arr[j][0]
                obj.lastName = arr[j][1]
                obj.gender = arr[j][2]
                obj.age = 'Invalid Birth Year'
            }
            console.log(obj)  
        }
    }
  }

  // TEST CASES
  changeMe([['Christ', 'Evans', 'Male', 1982], ['Robert', 'Downey', 'Male']]);
```

Comment: you're looping over the array you pass in with your inner for loop. This array contains two arrays. So, you'll create two objects and also log both objects. Your inner loop runs once for every element in your array (as persons.length = arr.length)

Comment: Variables `i` and `j` should be declared.

Comment: I see ... so what's your idea, nick? should I add break; or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

```
function changeMe(arr) {
    // you can only write your code here!
    if(arr.length==0){
        console.log( '""')
    }else{
        let person = [];
    let person1 = [];
    for(i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        person.push(`${i+1}. ${arr[i][0]} ${arr[i][1]}`)
    }

        for(j=0;j<arr.length;j++){
            var subObj = {}
            if(arr[j].length==4 && 2020-arr[j][3]>0){
                subObj.firstName = arr[j][0]
                subObj.lastName =  arr[j][1]
                subObj.gender = arr[j][2]
                subObj.age = 2020 - arr[j][3]
            }else{
                subObj.firstName = arr[j][0]
                subObj.lastName = arr[j][1]
                subObj.gender = arr[j][2]
                subObj.age = 'Invalid Birth Year'
            }
            person1.push(subObj) 
        }

    for(i=0;i<person.length;i++){
        for(j=0;j<person1.length;j++){
            if(i==j){
                console.log(person[i])
                console.log(person1[i])
            }
        }
    }
    }

  }

  // TEST CASES
  changeMe([['Christ', 'Evans', 'Male', 1982], ['Robert', 'Downey', 'Male']]); // 1. Christ Evans:
  // { firstName: 'Christ',
  //   lastName: 'Evans',
  //   gender: 'Male',
  //   age: 37 }
  // 2. Robert Downey:
  // { firstName: 'Robert',
  //   lastName: 'Downey',
  //   gender: 'Male',
  //   age: 'Invalid Birth Year' }
  changeMe([]); // ""
```